# Failed to start Hadoop services: localhost: nice: cannot set niceness: Permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hadoop

I'm trying to install Hadoop on Ubuntu as Windows subsystem, the installation is finished, but I'm getting error while starting Hadoop services.

```
$ start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-DESKTOP-HD9EL6C.out
localhost: nice: cannot set niceness: Permission denied
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-DESKTOP-HD9EL6C.out
localhost: nice: cannot set niceness: Permission denied
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-DESKTOP-HD9EL6C.out
0.0.0.0: nice: cannot set niceness: Permission denied
```

I tried many solutions from different platforms, but nothing seems to work.

Any solution?

Comment: Script is located inside /usr/local/hadoop/sbin.

Comment: You can have a look at this link: http://codesfusion.blogspot.com/2013/10/setup-hadoop-2x-220-on-ubuntu.html?m=1 
I have followed these steps to install hadoop.